# Being able to print before declaring. PYTHON

Tags: python, import

It's quite straight forward, and I bet it's a noob question.

Why is it that the following can print the year BEFORE declaring it, as it is shown in the code

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
print now.year
current_year = now.year
current_month = now.month
current_day = now.day
```

This shows 2015, as it should, but how is it possible to pring out now.year, when I haven't even declared it at that point.

Comment: What is "declaring"? I don't think Python has that.

Comment: What I mean is that, how can I do print now.year, without actually having anything that is named now.year? I mean, now.year doesn't exist. Is Python smart enough to figure out that I am calling only a part of the datetime?

Comment: How so you haven't "declared" it? You have `now = datetime.now()` there.

Comment: I think that the confusion here is how python's object model works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`datetime.now()` returns a date object, which has a member named year.  What you are doing here:

```
current_year = now.year
current_month = now.month
current_day = now.day
```

is assigning local variables, not assigning the members of now.